# How can I create an entity with a translatable snippet as name

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to create a new customer group in a plugin. The name of this customer group should be translatable. How can I achieve this? Here is my code until now:

```
$customerGroupRepository->create([
            [
                'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
                'registrationActive' => false,
                'displayGross' => true,
                'translations' => [
                    Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => [
                        'name' => 'Customer group',
                    ],
                    'de_DE' => [
                        'name' => 'Kundengruppe',
                    ],
                    'en_GB' => [
                        'name' => 'Customer group',
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ], $context);
```

But this doesn't work. The name of the customer group is allways 'Customer group' no matter which language I choose in the shopware backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locales need to include hyphens: `de-DE`, `en-GB`

Using the correct locale they should be resolved to a `language.id`.

Generally speaking it wouldn't be a bad idea though to first fetch the `id` of the `language` entities and then use them as the key instead. Just as a precaution to make sure the language/locale exists.

With `language.id`:

```php
[
    // ...
    'translations' => [
        Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => [
            'name' => 'Customer group',
        ],
        '9e4f6342174749aa897c5b64d57d7996' => [
            'name' => 'Kundengruppe',
        ],
        '0a7f24f26e48436d9f3b343fc43b65b7' => [
            'name' => 'Customer group',
        ]
    ]
]
```

With locale:

```php
[
    // ...
    'translations' => [
        Defaults::LANGUAGE_SYSTEM => [
            'name' => 'Customer group',
        ],
        'de-DE' => [
            'name' => 'Kundengruppe',
        ],
        'en-GB' => [
            'name' => 'Customer group',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Should both work.